# Return HTML Template Page with PHP Function

Tags: php, shortcode, templates

I want to create a form that I can use a shortcode to insert into my site.

It would be really nice if I could create the HTML part in a seperate file and then insert it with a PHP shortcode (to seperate the logic of the page from the mechanics of making it into a shortcode).

How could I do this?

### -- Update --

This is what I've done:
I have two files.  One called 'profiletemplate.php' and one called 'scodes'.  They are both part of a plugin that I am making for my site with an init.php that initializes them.  Here is their content:

**init.php**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/pages/scodes.php');
?>
```

**scodes.php**

```
function jf_testcode() {
    include dirname(__FILE__) . 'profiletemplate.php';
}

add_shortcode('testfield', 'jf_testcode');
```

**profiletemplate.php**

```
<?php // Template for my form shortcode ?>
<form>
Testing
</form>
```

I then use the [testfield] shortcode on a page in my site.

### Update 2

So this method is working, but it isn't inserting the HTML where the shortcode is called. Instead it is just inserting the content at the top of the page (like if I said 'echo 'Testing'' instead of 'return 'Testing'' in a function.

Comment: Well, for starters, you CAN write plain HTML in a PHP file. You then have to write a function in your `functions.php` that requires/includes this certain file, and by means of `add_shortcode()` set up your desired shortcode to call your function.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something I forgot in my previous comment was that shortcodes *return* content, both the suggested `include` and my alternative [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) will directly output the content (which is what you are seeing with the content appearing at the top of your page instead of where the shortcode is called).  To counteract this we must use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832179/383847).

Define the shortcode in your functions.php (or your site's [site-specific functions](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/) file).

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part('my_form_template');
    return ob_get_clean();   
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```

Then in your theme folder you need a file called `my_form_template.php` which will be loaded anywhere you place the shortcode.

Comment: Perfect!  This works fabulously!

Comment: If you try to do the same within a plugin you need to use include. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124794/75817

Comment: Wow...saved my day..awesome code

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your **functions.php**:

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
    include dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'my_form_template.php';
} // function my_form_shortcode
add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```

File **my_form_template.php**:

```
<?php // Template for my form shortcode ?>
<form ...>
    FIELDS
</form>
```

Comment: You could also use `get_template_part()` inside your shortcode function.

Comment: I tried implementing @t f's solution - I added an update to my post about it

Comment: @helgatheviking - how does that function work?

Comment: See the codex for a description of [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) and see my answer for how to use it in conjunction with your shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

try to put all your code inside `ob_start();` and `return ob_get_clean();`
and that will solve the problem of the short code content appear at the top because `ob_` is a buffer so it get all the prev code do your stuff then continue where its stopped .

full example .

```
function subscribe_model_fn(){
ob_start();

// your code in sprated file happy and will arranged 
include(locate_template( 'library/general/subscribe_model.php',false,true));

return ob_get_clean();
}


add_shortcode('subscribe_model', 'subscribe_model_fn');
```