# How to include a file using get_template_part() in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, get-template-part

A very simple question may be, but I'm struggling. In theme development, I worked with `get_template_part()` many times, and I understand its basics. But when I's developing a plugin, I wondered using it showing me some errors:

> **Notice: Use of undefined constant STYLESHEETPATH** - assumed 'STYLESHEETPATH' in `...\wp-includes\template.php` on line 407

and

> **Notice: Use of undefined constant TEMPLATEPATH** - assumed 'TEMPLATEPATH' in `...\wp-includes\template.php` on line 410

Googling the problem showed a support fix:

- [Use `get_template_part()` into a plugin - WordPress Support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-get_template_part-into-a-plugin)

But that seems a huge workaround - I doubt it. I think that shouldn't be much complicated. I checked this [WPSE Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41640/22728) and found this line of code:

```
if ( '' === locate_template( 'loop-mycustomposttype.php', true, false ) )
    include( 'loop-mycustomposttype.php' );
```

Where there is a PHP `include()` function. As per as my WordPress knowledge I learned to prefer `get_template_part()` over PHP `include()`. Then how exactly I can use a simple `get_template_part()` in my plugin.

I'm not using any loop or something, I'm just separating (or you may say organizing) my plugin code into different files so that in some cases, I will simply comment them out to drop where they are not necessary. I tried:

```
get_template_part( 'my', 'special-admin' );
```

and then after the error, changed it to:

```
get_template_part( 'my', 'specialadmin' );
```

But you know that's not the issue. I'm on local server, using WAMP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is a *theme* function. You can't load plugin files with that function. Take a look at the source and you will notice the work is done by [`locate_template`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L132). [Look at that source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/template.php#L402) and you will see that it always loads from *theme* directories.

However much you may want to use `get_template_part` it is the wrong function.

You will need to `include` your files.

The reason, so it seems to me, for `get_template_part` is to allow themes to be extended-- aka, to ease the creation of child themes. Plugins are not intended to be extended in that way so there is no need for `get_template_part` or for any plugin equivalent.

Answer (score 15):

@s_ha_dum is correct that `get_template_part` is a theme function, but he is incorrect that plugins are not intended to be extended in this way. It is simply more complicated.

[This post](https://pippinsplugins.com/template-file-loaders-plugins/) by Pippin, describes how to use a function that will do the work of loading your plugin templates, while allowing users to override your plugin templates within their theme .

Essentially, it looks in a special folder in the theme, then if not found there, it looks within the templates folder for the plugin.

Answer (score 7):

As was said before, you can't use `get_template_part` in plugins, but there's a [handy class](https://github.com/GaryJones/Gamajo-Template-Loader) on Github (created by Gary Jones) that mimics the `get_template_part` functionality in plugins, adding the plugin to the fallback (child theme > parent theme > plugin).

In this way, you can override your plugin’s ”template part“ inside a child theme or a parent theme.

Usage (taken from the Github repo instructions):

1. Copy `class-gamajo-template-loader.php` into your plugin. It can be into a file in the plugin root, or better, an includes directory.
2. Create a new file, such as `class-your-plugin-template-loader.php`, in the same directory.
3. Create a `class` in that file that extends `Gamajo_Template_Loader`.
4. Override the class properties to suit your plugin. You could also override the `get_templates_dir()` method if it isn't right for you.
5. You can now instantiate your custom template loader class, and use it to call the `get_template_part()` method. This could be within a shortcode callback, or something you want theme developers to include in their files.

Example code:

```
// Template loader instantiated elsewhere, such as the main plugin file.
$meal_planner_template_loader = new Meal_Planner_Template_Loader;

// Use it to call the get_template_part() method. This could be within 
// a shortcode callback, or something you want theme developers 
// to include in their files.
$meal_planner_template_loader->get_template_part( 'recipe' );

// If you want to pass data to the template, call the set_template_data() 
// method with an array before calling get_template_part().        
// set_template_data() returns the loader object to allow for method chaining.
$data = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'boom' );

$meal_planner_template_loader
    ->set_template_data( $data );
    ->get_template_part( 'recipe' );

// The value of bar is now available inside the recipe template as $data->foo.
// If you wish to use a different variable name, add a second parameter 
// to set_template_data():
$data = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'boom' );

$meal_planner_template_loader
    ->set_template_data( $data, 'context' )
    ->get_template_part( 'recipe', 'ingredients' );

// The value of bar is now available inside the recipe template as $context->foo.
```