# How can you include a theme template file from within a plugin (i.e. WooCommerce's Shop page)?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to customise WooCommerce's Shop page (called 'Products' in this instance) to include a template part from my main WordPress theme.

**get_template_part()** does not work. I believe that's because a plugin can't tell which files will exist in a theme so it's disabled. Alternatively, I wonder if it's because the function is being called from within the plugin directory, so it's looking in the wrong directory.

**include()** does not work. I  get the following errors:

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in ...\woocommerce\archive-product.php on line 52
Warning: include(.../partials/acf-flexible-layout.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in ...\woocommerce\archive-product.php on line 52
Warning: include(): Failed opening '.../partials/acf-flexible-layout.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in ...\woocommerce\archive-product.php on line 52
```

note: the three dots (...) in the file paths are a reference to my theme.

Something else to note is that the template part I'm trying to include reference Advanced Custom Fields associated with the Products / Shop page in WordPress.

**copying the template part's code directly into the archive-product.php** does not work. I'm not sure why this is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT**
I have already checked [How to include a file using get_template_part() in a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124789/how-to-include-a-file-using-get-template-part-in-a-plugin) but it doesn't seem suitable:

1. The answer chosen gives `include()` as a solution. I've already said this doesn't work for me.
2. It's not a plugin **I'm** developing. It's WooCommerce. Any updates to the plugin could delete the files I add / change.
3. I don't fully understand [the other promising answer](https://pippinsplugins.com/template-file-loaders-plugins/) given, so I'm not able to adapt it to suit my needs (if that's even possible).

Comment: Did you tried this, already?
 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124789/how-to-include-a-file-using-get-template-part-in-a-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a file using get\_template\_part() in a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124789/how-to-include-a-file-using-get-template-part-in-a-plugin)

Comment: FYI that's the same post, duplicated. I have edited my answer to explain that I have reviewed that answer already. It may help, or the solution may be in there, but I can't see it at the moment.

Comment: You know that you can [override WooCommerce templates in your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), right?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I already have a number of overrides.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to this, at least in my specific case.

---

**Solution**

`get_template_part()` did work in the end, but ACF needed the ID of the post (the Shop page). When calling ACF fields from outside of the loop you need to specify a post ID.

For all of the other pages on the site where the template is being used, it knew the ID already so I didn't have to specify. Seemingly, where I was calling it from in archive-product.php was outside of the loop. If someone could clarify that, it may be helpful.

So, in archive-product.php:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'partials/acf', 'a-template-file' ); ?>
```

Then in the template file:

```
$post_id = '';
if ( is_shop() ) {
    $post_id = 20;  // 20 being the ID of my Shop page
} else {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
}

if ( have_rows('flexible_content_layout', $post_id) ) {

    while ( have_rows('flexible_content_layout', $post_id) ) {

        the_row();

        // etc, etc...
```

Comment: You can use this `$post_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );` to get the ID of the shop page rather than hard coding it.